# httpd error log "Error: Document has not the mandatory ending %EOF"

Tags: centos, php, httpd

The company I work for recently outsourced a website rebuild, and along with it came a CMS.

Despite my lack of expertise, I am the nominated server expert. Go Figure.

---

Anyway, when trying to upload .pdfs to the CMS we cant upload anything over 1Mb.
I have checked the php.ini and the .htaccess files and they are currently:

```
post_max_size = 15M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Now to the main point of this question, the error logs show the following:

```
Error: Document has not the mandatory ending %EOF
```

However, when I open the PDF in notepad++ it certainly does have `%EOF` as the very last line.

Currently the server is running PHP 5.5 and CentOS 5.11

So really I'm just hoping someone has experienced this before and has a solution, none of my googling is helping!

Comment: What's the CMS ?

Comment: @Iain Its a custom Content Management System written by the people who made our site.

Comment: With all due respect, you're going to have the best luck contacting the support/developers of the CMS.

Comment: @BrandonXavier They refuse to help because they claim its a server issue. Apparently on their test server it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is much we can do to help here. The wording of that error message is a little odd but the internet has [little information on it](https://www.google.com/search?q=Error%3A%20Document%20has%20not%20the%20mandatory%20ending%20%25EOF).

There are several things I would try

- I would ask the developers if that message is one that their CMS generates and try to work with them to solve the issue. If it's not within their software then I'd be looking to track down what does generate it and use that as a starting point.
- Your system is, whilst supported, somewhat elderly you really shouldn't be developing for CentOS 5.11 any more without a very good reason. I would get a VM with a more recent version of CentOS (6.7 or 7.1), install the CMS and it's dependencies and then do some testing.